# Can't compile with both arm6 and arm7?

Tags: ios

I'm trying to build a static library for both the arm6 and arm7 architectures. However, when I use the following command to build for arm6:

```
~/Documents/development2/iphoneapp/libVoalte/Vendor/silk/SILK_SDK_SRC_v1.0.8/SILK_SDK_SRC_ARM_v1.0.8 ~/Documents/development2/iphoneapp/libVoalte/Vendor/silk/SILK_SDK_SRC_v1.0.8
rm -f libSKP_SILK_SDK.a* src/SKP_Silk_A2NLSF.o src/SKP_Silk_CNG.o src/SKP_Silk_HP_variable_cutoff_FIX.o src/SKP_Silk_LBRR_reset.o src/SKP_Silk_LPC_inv_pred_gain.o src/SKP_Silk_LPC_synthesis_filter.o src/SKP_Silk_LPC_synthesis_order16.o src/SKP_Silk_LP_variable_cutoff.o src/SKP_Silk_LSF_cos_table.o src/SKP_Silk_LTP_analysis_filter_FIX.o src/SKP_Silk_LTP_scale_ctrl_FIX.o src/SKP_Silk_MA.o src/SKP_Silk_NLSF2A.o src/SKP_Silk_NLSF2A_stable.o src/SKP_Silk_NLSF_MSVQ_decode.o src/SKP_Silk_NLSF_MSVQ_encode_FIX.o src/SKP_Silk_NLSF_VQ_rate_distortion_FIX.o src/SKP_Silk_NLSF_VQ_sum_error_FIX.o src/SKP_Silk_NLSF_VQ_weights_laroia.o src/SKP_Silk_NLSF_stabilize.o src/SKP_Silk_NSQ.o src/SKP_Silk_NSQ_del_dec.o src/SKP_Silk_PLC.o src/SKP_Silk_VAD.o src/SKP_Silk_VQ_nearest_neighbor_FIX.o src/SKP_Silk_ana_filt_bank_1.o src/SKP_Silk_apply_sine_window_new.o src/SKP_Silk_array_maxabs.o src/SKP_Silk_autocorr.o src/SKP_Silk_biquad.o src/SKP_Silk_biquad_alt.o src/SKP_Silk_burg_modified.o src/SKP_Silk_bwexpander.o src/SKP_Silk_bwexpander_32.o src/SKP_Silk_code_signs.o src/SKP_Silk_control_audio_bandwidth.o src/SKP_Silk_control_codec_FIX.o src/SKP_Silk_corrMatrix_FIX.o src/SKP_Silk_create_init_destroy.o src/SKP_Silk_dec_API.o src/SKP_Silk_decode_core.o src/SKP_Silk_decode_frame.o src/SKP_Silk_decode_parameters.o src/SKP_Silk_decode_pitch.o src/SKP_Silk_decode_pulses.o src/SKP_Silk_decoder_set_fs.o src/SKP_Silk_detect_SWB_input.o src/SKP_Silk_enc_API.o src/SKP_Silk_encode_frame_FIX.o src/SKP_Silk_encode_parameters.o src/SKP_Silk_encode_pulses.o src/SKP_Silk_find_LPC_FIX.o src/SKP_Silk_find_LTP_FIX.o src/SKP_Silk_find_pitch_lags_FIX.o src/SKP_Silk_find_pred_coefs_FIX.o src/SKP_Silk_gain_quant.o src/SKP_Silk_init_encoder_FIX.o src/SKP_Silk_inner_prod_aligned.o src/SKP_Silk_interpolate.o src/SKP_Silk_k2a.o src/SKP_Silk_k2a_Q16.o src/SKP_Silk_lin2log.o src/SKP_Silk_log2lin.o src/SKP_Silk_noise_shape_analysis_FIX.o src/SKP_Silk_pitch_analysis_core.o src/SKP_Silk_pitch_est_tables.o src/SKP_Silk_prefilter_FIX.o src/SKP_Silk_process_NLSFs_FIX.o src/SKP_Silk_process_gains_FIX.o src/SKP_Silk_quant_LTP_gains_FIX.o src/SKP_Silk_range_coder.o src/SKP_Silk_regularize_correlations_FIX.o src/SKP_Silk_resampler.o src/SKP_Silk_resampler_down2.o src/SKP_Silk_resampler_down2_3.o src/SKP_Silk_resampler_down3.o src/SKP_Silk_resampler_private_AR2.o src/SKP_Silk_resampler_private_ARMA4.o src/SKP_Silk_resampler_private_IIR_FIR.o src/SKP_Silk_resampler_private_copy.o src/SKP_Silk_resampler_private_down4.o src/SKP_Silk_resampler_private_down_FIR.o src/SKP_Silk_resampler_private_up2_HQ.o src/SKP_Silk_resampler_private_up4.o src/SKP_Silk_resampler_rom.o src/SKP_Silk_resampler_up2.o src/SKP_Silk_residual_energy16_FIX.o src/SKP_Silk_residual_energy_FIX.o src/SKP_Silk_scale_copy_vector16.o src/SKP_Silk_scale_vector.o src/SKP_Silk_schur.o src/SKP_Silk_schur64.o src/SKP_Silk_shell_coder.o src/SKP_Silk_sigm_Q15.o src/SKP_Silk_solve_LS_FIX.o src/SKP_Silk_sort.o src/SKP_Silk_sum_sqr_shift.o src/SKP_Silk_tables_LTP.o src/SKP_Silk_tables_NLSF_CB0_10.o src/SKP_Silk_tables_NLSF_CB0_16.o src/SKP_Silk_tables_NLSF_CB1_10.o src/SKP_Silk_tables_NLSF_CB1_16.o src/SKP_Silk_tables_gain.o src/SKP_Silk_tables_other.o src/SKP_Silk_tables_pitch_lag.o src/SKP_Silk_tables_pulses_per_block.o src/SKP_Silk_tables_sign.o src/SKP_Silk_tables_type_offset.o src/SKP_Silk_warped_autocorrelation_FIX.o test/Encoder.o test/Decoder.o \
          test/signalCompare.o  \
          encoder decoder signalcompare
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_A2NLSF.o src/SKP_Silk_A2NLSF.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_CNG.o src/SKP_Silk_CNG.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_HP_variable_cutoff_FIX.o src/SKP_Silk_HP_variable_cutoff_FIX.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_LBRR_reset.o src/SKP_Silk_LBRR_reset.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_LPC_inv_pred_gain.o src/SKP_Silk_LPC_inv_pred_gain.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_LPC_synthesis_filter.o src/SKP_Silk_LPC_synthesis_filter.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_LPC_synthesis_order16.o src/SKP_Silk_LPC_synthesis_order16.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_LP_variable_cutoff.o src/SKP_Silk_LP_variable_cutoff.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_LSF_cos_table.o src/SKP_Silk_LSF_cos_table.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_LTP_analysis_filter_FIX.o src/SKP_Silk_LTP_analysis_filter_FIX.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_LTP_scale_ctrl_FIX.o src/SKP_Silk_LTP_scale_ctrl_FIX.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_MA.o src/SKP_Silk_MA.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_NLSF2A.o src/SKP_Silk_NLSF2A.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_NLSF2A_stable.o src/SKP_Silk_NLSF2A_stable.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_NLSF_MSVQ_decode.o src/SKP_Silk_NLSF_MSVQ_decode.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_NLSF_MSVQ_encode_FIX.o src/SKP_Silk_NLSF_MSVQ_encode_FIX.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_NLSF_VQ_rate_distortion_FIX.o src/SKP_Silk_NLSF_VQ_rate_distortion_FIX.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_NLSF_VQ_sum_error_FIX.o src/SKP_Silk_NLSF_VQ_sum_error_FIX.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_NLSF_VQ_weights_laroia.o src/SKP_Silk_NLSF_VQ_weights_laroia.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_NLSF_stabilize.o src/SKP_Silk_NLSF_stabilize.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_NSQ.o src/SKP_Silk_NSQ.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_NSQ_del_dec.o src/SKP_Silk_NSQ_del_dec.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_PLC.o src/SKP_Silk_PLC.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_VAD.o src/SKP_Silk_VAD.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_VQ_nearest_neighbor_FIX.o src/SKP_Silk_VQ_nearest_neighbor_FIX.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_ana_filt_bank_1.o src/SKP_Silk_ana_filt_bank_1.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_apply_sine_window_new.o src/SKP_Silk_apply_sine_window_new.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_array_maxabs.o src/SKP_Silk_array_maxabs.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_autocorr.o src/SKP_Silk_autocorr.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_biquad.o src/SKP_Silk_biquad.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_biquad_alt.o src/SKP_Silk_biquad_alt.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_burg_modified.o src/SKP_Silk_burg_modified.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_bwexpander.o src/SKP_Silk_bwexpander.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_bwexpander_32.o src/SKP_Silk_bwexpander_32.c
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3   -Iinterface -Isrc -Itest -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o src/SKP_Silk_code_signs.o src/SKP_Silk_code_signs.c
```

I'm seeing fat file returned that is also build for arm7:
    lipo -info libSKP_SILK_SDK.6.a 
    Architectures in the fat file: libSKP_SILK_SDK.6.a are: armv6 armv7

However, the file actually doesn't work for arm6 and arm7, only arm6. If I rebuild for arm7, it works as expected and doesn't report it as a fat file.

Comment: That's just one compile line. That should have just created an `armv6` version. That can't be the only line you run so can you show us your link line as well / any other things you run please?

Comment: Nice to see some more, but where's the final link?

Comment: The problem ended up being that the MakeFile wasn't cleaning all the older armv6 object files before attempting to compile the armv7.  So I ended up with a static library that was half armv6 and half armv7.  Once I fixed the Makefile it compiled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're doing, but I don't see the same problem. Consider this:

```
$ /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -mcpu=arm1136jf-s -mtune=arm1136jf-s -march=armv6 -Wall -enable-threads -O3 -O3 -DIPHONE -DNEON -marm -I/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib -o test.o test.c

$ file test.o 
test-bbb.o: Mach-O object arm

$ otool -hV test.o 
test.o:
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
   MH_MAGIC     ARM         V6  0x00      OBJECT     3        568 SUBSECTIONS_VIA_SYMBOLS

$ lipo -info test.o
Non-fat file: test.o is architecture: armv6
```

It must be something to do with commands that are being run after the ones you've shown. For instance you've not shown us the linker command being run to make `libSKP_SILK_SDK.6.a`.